# When is a class template depending on a incomplete type as a template argument instantiated?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
class I;

template<class T>
struct P
{
    T t;
};

template<class T>
struct F
{
    operator bool() {return false;}
};


int main()
{
    int a = F<P<I>>();
    int b = !F<P<I>>();
    int c = int(F<P<I>>());
    int d = !int(F<P<I>>());
}
```

Are the evaluations in the initializers above well-formed? Why or why not? Which rules in the standard mandate the behavior?

Comment: Ill formed templates don't compile, unless you have a bug in the compiler.

Comment: The reason `b` doesn't compile is because of ADL, `P<I>` needs to be instantiated to look for some `T operator!(F<P<I>>)` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specializations are instantiated only if a complete type is required or affects the semantics in the given context. [[temp.inst]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.inst#2)

So the default behavior is not to do any implicit instantiation if not necessary.

In all the cases you have shown, the specializations of `F` need to be instantiated because `T()` requires `T` to be complete. However, nothing in the instantiation of `F<P<I>>` requires `P<I>` to be complete, so it will not be instantiated with it.

None of the conversions to `int` require `P<I>` to be complete either and so the initializations of `a`, `c` and `d` don't cause any instantiation of `P<I>` at all and they are well-formed.

However, for `b` the situation is a bit different. In order to determine which `operator!` overload to call, unqualified name lookup and argument-dependent name lookup of `operator!` is done.

Argument-dependent lookup looks for `operator!` declarations in multiple scopes related to the type `F<P<I>>`.

First, for `F` itself, it includes `F`'s class scope and the enclosing namespace scope, meaning the global scope. However, secondly, it also includes the class- and enclosing namespace scope of types in the template arguments of the type, meaning that it includes `P<I>`'s class scope as well.

In order to determine whether there is an `operator!` overload in `P<I>`, it must be instantiated. While instantiating `P<I>` the declaration `T t;` is also instantiated as `I t;`, which requires `I` to be complete, but which it isn't, making the initialization of `b` ill-formed.

---

However [[temp.inst]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.inst#9) allows, but doesn't require, the instantiation to be skipped if it isn't needed to determine the result of overload resolution. I am not sure how wide this permission is supposed to be interpreted, but if it does apply here, then it is unspecified whether instantiation of `P<I>` for the initialization of `b` happens.

Comment: _In order to determine whether there is an operator! overload in P<I>, it must be instantiated._ Is it necessary for all implementations? Doesn't https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.inst#9 apply?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I could be wrong, but from the example and the description of [CWG 2222](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2222) it seems to me that this is meant to apply only if the existence of an overload in the class cannot affect the result of overload resolution, rather than allowing inference from the template definition before it is instantiated. But I suppose the wording is wider than that.

Comment: Nice catch of CWG 2222. However, the current wording really seems to allow it totally unspecified. Suppose a super smart implementation being able to enumerate all names in the TUs of the program and it find no `operator!` at all, then it can prove that no instantiation is ever required to determine `!`.